# ArcMap tool for for mapping and measuring methane, considering variable parameters

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, model

I have data on 70 methane-emitting plants. For each plant I have the average data of temperature and precipitation between the years 2000-2014. In addition, each plant also has relative humidity, wind speed, and wind direction in the azimuth.  each plant is also fed the total amount of emissions, coordinates and type of plant. So far from what I have found, to show the distribution of spatial pollution on a map, the most appropriate tool is krigging. Is there a tool that can also give weight to wind and humidity data in addition to methane quantities? In order to have a more reliable model according to the different parameters.
I use ArcMap 10.6.1 , can also try in QGIS if relevant

Comment: You probably would use [cokriging](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/understanding-cokriging.htm), which is available in the Geostatistical Analyst extension of ArcGIS.

Comment: Please remember to focus your question on one software package. Two platforms is effectively two questions, which violates the One question per Question principle.

Comment: I expect 3D fluid dynamics to be important except in very flat terrain with gentle, horizontal, wind. However - assuming that concern to be unwarranted in this case - one option might use the flow accumulation tool by creating a flow direction raster to represent the wind direction and an absorption surface represent the rate at which the methane escapes to other systems.  To make the flow direction raster would be tricky, a specialist model may be less problematic. Here is a nice intro https://www.intechopen.com/books/air-quality-models-and-applications/urban-air-pollution-modeling